# Freemarker custom characters escaping (escaping LaTeX special characters)

Tags: java, latex, pdf-generation, freemarker

What is the best way to escape special latex characters when using freemarker to create a .tex file?

Currently, I am passing a java function for escaping symbols and I have to wrap every variable into this function call. I know that freemarker has built-in escaping for some formats, but sadly latex is not supported.

This is how I do it at the moment:

```
${escapeFormatter.escapeSymbols(some.value)!}
```

I don't like it that I have to manually call this function for every value. How can I make it more generic?

Comment: Can you be specific what kind of latex characters you want escape? There are many ways you can escape a spl characters.

Comment: @soorapadman  As far as I know, these & % $ # _ { } ~ ^ \ are the "special: characters for latex, so I'd like to escape them. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34580/escape-character-in-latex Here you can find how they are supposed to be escape (the first answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register your own "output format" via `freemarker.template.Configuration#setRegisteredCustomOutputFormats`. Then those can be used with the auto-escaping feature, just like the standard ones (see: https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_misc_autoescaping.html). See also `OutputFormat` and `MarkupOutputFormat` API documentation, and implementations in the source code as an example.